# What is the chemical equation for extracting biodiesel from cooking oil? (Half complete)

Tags: organic-chemistry

what i got so far:

(k,1,m,n,o is a constant because i dont know the ratio between the chemicals used in the reaction)

kCooking oil(l) + lCH3OH + mNaOH -> nBiodiesel + oC3H8O3

can you tell me the chemical formula for cooking oil and biodiesel, and fill out the constants for me? thanks :D

Comment: Neither biodiesel nor cooking oil is a specific chemical substance, so they do not have a certain chemical formula.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you made a slight mistake here in the question. NaOH does not take part in the reaction at all.It acts as a catalyst.

The question should be:-
                             NaOH or KOH
k Cooking oil + l CH3OH ----------------------> n Biodiesel + o C3H8O3.(k,l,n,o be the variables).

Now the cooking oil and the biodiesel are both esters.Converting vegetable oil into biodiesel is called a transesterification reaction.The reaction is given below in form of a diagram.

[image]

So the reaction ends up with all gaps filled as:-

C51H98O6(COOKING OIL)+3 CH3OH(METHANOL)->3 C17H34O2(Biodiesel)+ C3H8O3(Glycerol)

SO k=1

l=3

m=invalid as NaOH is catalyst so it does not take part in reaction directly.

n=3

o=1

(GENERAL formula of cooking oil is C51H98O6 and that of biodiesel is C17H34O2.)

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much man. that really helped me

Comment: You are always Welcome.